# Always show child div when a scrollable parent div is opened

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have a div with multiple div inside it such that user can scroll through it. It is toggle - show/hide on click of a button.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv" id="one"></div>
    <div class="innerDiv" id="two"></div>
    <div class="innerDiv" id="three"></div>
    <div class="innerDiv" id="four"></div>
    <div class="innerDiv" id="five"></div>
    <div class="innerDiv" id="six"></div>
    <div class="innerDiv" id="seven"></div>
    <div class="innerDiv" id="eight"></div>
    <div class="innerDiv" id="nine"></div>
    <div class="innerDiv" id="ten"></div>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="opnLnk">Open Popup</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="clsLnk">Close Popup</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mainDiv {width:300px; height:350px; border:1px solid #000; background-color:palegreen; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto}
.innerDiv {width:298px; border:1px solid green; height:50px}
#three {background-color:red}
.innerDiv:nth-child(odd) {background-color:green}
.innerDiv:nth-child(even) {background-color:blue}
#opnLnk, #clsLnk {right:30px; right:30px; position:absolute}
#opnLnk {top:30px}
#clsLnk {top:70px}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#opnLnk").click(function(){
    // need a script to always show red div
    $("#mainDiv").show();
});

$("#clsLnk").click(function(){
    $("#mainDiv").hide();
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/PSSdC/

When user had scrolled to the bottom, he closes the popup and again opens. what I want is to show red (#three) div always at the top line when popup is always opened

I have already tried jquery scrollTop method but since I have a ajax content loaded in it, I need some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Add a function `scrollToElement` to your js.

```
function scrollToElement(ele) {
$("#mainDiv").scrollTop(ele.offset().top).scrollLeft(ele.offset().left);
}
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PSSdC/4/

Comment: Your solution should work but not sure I ran into some problem. I have used scrollTop(0) on close rather than on open and it easily solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to scroll the div to the top after any toggle complete event.

```
$("#clkLnk").click(function(){
    // need a script to always show red div
    $("#mainDiv").toggle("slow",function(){
         $("#mainDiv").scrollTop(0);
    });
});
```

working Example: 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PSSdC/3/)

Comment: Your solution is working fine for my fiddle. I have already tried scrollTop(0). But as I am dynamically loading content it is not useful in my scenario.

Comment: How you dynamically loading the content? can you show your code? are you doing it with ajax? are you override the "mainDiv"? ot you just change his html content by $("mainDiv").html("fromajax")?

Comment: I am using jstree api. I am having a tree inside `.mainDiv`. I cannot use success like in normal ajax. Though that api provides loaded.jstree .... but it is called when the response is received from server and not when tree's html is created